# rmarkdown format letter how to align names and signatures

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am using rmarkdown to generate formal letters that include 2 signature positions. I would like the names and positions to be at the left and right margin of the document but with left aligned. The names and positions are of different lengths so `\hfill` and `\hspace{110pt}` does not do the job.  Above the name the signature should be centre aligned. I am using a table to do this like

````
    ---
title: ""
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

df<-data.frame(name=c("Tom Short", "Gagagagagagaga Long"), position=c("CEO", "Chief Technology Evangelist and Much Much More"))

```


\
\


![](JohnHancocksSignature.png){width=25%} \hfill ![](JohnHancocksSignature.png){width=25%} 

\
\begingroup
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
Nina Static & \hspace{110pt} & `r df$name[1]` \\
Chief Static & \hspace{110pt} & `r  df$position[1]`\\
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\
\
\
\
\
\
![](JohnHancocksSignature.png){width=25%} \hfill ![](JohnHancocksSignature.png){width=25%} 


\begingroup
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
Nina Static & \hspace{110pt} & `r df$name[2]` \\
Chief Static & \hspace{110pt} & `r  df$position[2]`\\
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
````

[image]

What I would like is that the names and positions are left aligned each underneath the other and the signature centered above like this

[image]

Comment: Make a picture in the paint, what do you want to see. It will be easier to understand for the answer ;)

Comment: thanks for the comment. You are right.

Comment: I'll see a little later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `varwidth` package like this:

````
---
title: ""
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{varwidth}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

df<-data.frame(name=c("Tom Short", "Gagagagagagaga Long"), position=c("CEO", "Chief Technology Evangelist and Much Much More"))

```


\begin{varwidth}{.5\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\medskip

\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
Nina Static

Chief static
\end{varwidth}
\end{varwidth}
\hfill
\begin{varwidth}{.5\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\medskip

\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
`r df$name[1]`

`r  df$position[1]`
\end{varwidth}
\end{varwidth}

\begin{varwidth}{.5\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\medskip

\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
Nina Static

Chief static
\end{varwidth}
\end{varwidth}
\hfill
\begin{varwidth}{.5\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-duck}
\medskip

\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
`r df$name[2]`

`r  df$position[2]`
\end{varwidth}
\end{varwidth}
````

[image]

Comment: I have the problem that the figures (the ducks in this case) are not perfectly aligned horizontally (the second duck starts a bit higher) and the same goes for Nina Static and Tom Short. Tom Short is positioned higher. Any ideas?

Comment: You can pass positioning arguments like `[b]` to the `varwidth` environments, but to know which one you are looking for, I would need a [mre]

Comment: or use `\strut` in all the lines without descenders.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

Find out a better `\hspace` for your pics...

````
---
title: "Untitled"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx}
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

df<-data.frame(name=c("Tom Short", "Gagagagagagaga Long"), position=c("CEO", "Chief Technology Evangelist and Much Much More"))

```


\
\


\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{your_pic.png} \hspace{4.5cm} \includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{your_pic.png}

\
\begingroup
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
Nina Static & \hspace{110pt} & `r df$name[1]` \\
Chief Static & \hspace{110pt} & `r  df$position[1]`\\
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\
\
\
\
\
\
\includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{your_pic.png} \hspace{4.6cm}  \includegraphics[height=2.5cm]{your_pic.png}


\begingroup
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
Nina Static & \hspace{110pt} & `r df$name[2]` \\
Chief Static & \hspace{110pt} & `r  df$position[2]`\\
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
````

[image]